# Perl Form - Check Field Is Filled In

Tags: forms, perl

I have a HTML form and a variable is set if a particular field is filled in, a Perl script I have inherited.

```
    for (my $i; $i<@raw_search_value; $i++) {
    ...
    $album_search=1 if $raw_search_column[$i] eq 'album_id';
    $top40_history_search=1 if $raw_search_column[$i]=~/^top40/;
    $album_ID=$raw_search_value[$i] if $album_search;
    $album_title_search=1 if $raw_search_column[$i] eq 'album_title';
    }

    $album_title_search=1 if $raw_search_column[$i] eq 'album_title';
```

A form field called album_title. The code reiterates through the form fields using my $i; $i<@raw_search_value[$i]

However I want the variable album_title_search to be set to one if ONLY this field has been filled in and others haven't. 
In other words, Set to 1 if this field is filled in and other fields in the form are blank.

Can I do this with one line of Perl, or do I have to expand it to go through every field and check it is blank?

I'm a bit stuck with this and haven't dealt with Perl code very long. Would welcome any suggestions. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$album_title_search=1 
  if $raw_search_column[$i] eq 'album_title'
  && grep { length } @raw_search_value == 1   # only 1 value filled
  && length $raw_search_value[$i]             # and that value is for album_title
```

However it can be written much more concisely. Can you post some more code, particularly the loop, the `@raw_search_column` and the `@raw_search_value`?

Comment: Thanks Kenney, I have added a bit more in the original question. It's not my code originally but I'm trying to learn from it as I go. Should your suggestion be actually set in a separate for loop outside the current one?

Comment: Inside, since you use `$i`, but, I think there's a much cleaner solution if you construct a `%hash` with the key=>values for the CGI parameters.

Comment: That didn't quite work but I swapped  '1 == grep{length} raw_search_value' to 'grep{length} raw_search_value == 1' and it has worked perfectly.

Comment: I have amended your answer but I can't actually mark it as the answer yet until it has been "peer reviewed" apparently. Many thanks Kenney. Much appreciated

Comment: Btw, if you use something like [this](https://github.com/neonics/webtools/blob/master/cgi-bin/CGI.pm#L198) to parse the request, returning a `%form`, you could just `@filled_paramnames = grep { length $form{$_} } keys %form` and `$album_title_search = scalar(@filled_paramnames)==1 && $filled_paramnames[0]=='album_title'`.